# How to load nested Azure App Config settings as nested classes in .Net? (with IOptions pattern)

Tags: .net, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to load nested settings from Azure App Config to my nested classes in .Net and it doesn't work for me.

Here is my setting in Azure App Config:

`ReplicaService:CosmosDb:Url`

And here is my nested `AppSettings` class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public CosmosDbSettings CosmosDb { get; set; }
}

public class CosmosDbSettings
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            string appConfigurationConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfigurationConnectionString");
            builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(appConfigurationConnectionString);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ReplicaService"));
        })
    .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

And then later in code (in my test function) I am trying to get value like this:

```
public class UpdateUserReplicaDocument
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public UpdateUserReplicaDocument(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [Function("ConfigTest")]
    public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "config-test")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        var url = _appSettings.CosmosDb.Url;

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

        response.WriteString(url);

        return response;
    }
}
```

However it fails with null reference exception on this line: `var url = _appSettings.CosmosDb.Url;`

Aka settings are not loaded correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

It works if I don't use nested classes and just work with this setting `ReplicaService:CosmosDbUrl` and have a single AppSettings class with Url property on it directly

Anyone has any ideas? I feel I must be missing something obvious.